# unit testing service layer that uses hibernate and annotations, and no DAO

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, unit-testing, integration-testing

What is the best way to unit test/integration test the following :

```
@Service("fooService")
public class FooService {

  @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  /*** Get all **/
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public List<Foo> getAllFoos() {
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    final Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
    return crit.list();
  }
}
```

I am happy to using mockito, but was not sure how leverage its usefulness. Most cases I have seen require the dao/mock dao to be passed in as method parameter.

Obviously I will then extrapolate to more complex methods.

Comment: This is the dao - just because it's got service in the name doesn't make it so. There's not much to be gained from mocking Session etc. - unless you have a lot of logic in there. I'd run integration tests against an in-memory db.

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys I called it service becuase its where I put a lot of the app logic (obviously this method is rather simple), and just use hibernate to do all the normal dao stuff (save, update, select, delete), didn't really see the point of creating a whole dao layer just for ~2 lines accessing hibernate session.  So you think load up an app context and run the tests against db without mocking anything is the way to go ?

Comment: definately - Think about what are you be trying to test here: whether these methods return what they should from the database. There's not much point in mocking session and criteria here.

Comment: yeah thats I thought originally, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class is the DAO and there's not much to be gained from mocking Session etc. unless you have a lot of logic in there - if you do then that might be better placed in an actual service class or on the model itself.

Think about what are you be trying to test here: whether these methods return what they should from the database. I would run integration tests against an in-memory database.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the @Resource annotation on a method, it will be much easier to set up a test and configure the service with a mock implementation of a SessionFactory (if that was what you asked for).

```
@Service("fooService")
public class FooService {

  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
  public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
     this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

}
```

Comment: You *don't* need to put in on a method, but you would want expose either a constructor or setter for the `SessionFactory`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few things to decide:

- Whether you keep sessionFactory as a field or not. I guess you should.
- Whether to use constructor or setter injection. I prefer constructor injection.
- How you're going to mock the SessionFactory: write it by hand, use Mockito, EasyMock ... whichever you prefer.